# How to properly call the S3 file inside flutter streams?

Tags: flutter, amazon-s3, graphql, aws-amplify

I am bit confused on the how to call the `s3 objects` inside streams.

Get requests are billable in the AWS, so having an image inside the stream will cause too many requests to S3 object.

Is there any method being followed for the flutter widgets where it has an image and text content ( eg. events )

Answer (score 0):

Using a Stream doesn't necessarily mean that you'll frequently execute API calls. You may still use `Future` for API calls and add its response on the StreamController.

Here's an example.

```dart
// Let Repository contain API requests
final _repository = Repository();
final _albumFetcher = StreamController<List<AlbumModel>>();

Stream<List<AlbumModel>> get allAlbums => _albumFetcher.stream;

fetchAlbum() async {
  // Fetch data and add the response on your StreamController
  List<AlbumModel> listAlbums = await _repository.fetchAllAlbums();
  _albumFetcher.sink.add(listAlbums);
}
```

The Stream will only be updated when fechAlbum() is called. The Stream won't continuously send API requests to fetch data.

Here's a [sample](https://github.com/omatt/flutter-bloc-sample) that I've created that you can try out.

Answer (score -1):

There's a few ways to do this. One way is to [sign your request](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html) with [Signature V4](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html) and **POST** your file to S3.